# How can I reuse a tag already pushed to remote for a code merged later

Tags: git

I made a mistake of adding a tag to the master branch, without actually merging the code to master.

```
git tag -a submission/2 -m "submission/2"
git push origin submission/2
```

After that, I merged the code to the master.

Now, how can I reuse or merge the **submission/2** for master?

```
$ git log --oneline

947e861 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit_msg_5
6522cd1 (tag: submission/1) Commit_msg_4
3276b3d Commit_msg_3
e1ed480 Commit_msg_2
41148c4 Commit_msg_1

$ git show-ref
947e8619793951014d83634efbe7030bfdd5f6ac refs/heads/master
947e8619793951014d83634efbe7030bfdd5f6ac refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
947e8619793951014d83634efbe7030bfdd5f6ac refs/remotes/origin/master
a3515c50ae5f4029302a83009d700d6b94252fa1 refs/tags/submission/1
a6d02f30d02526b75441f0c4d69489b2d763a1fa refs/tags/submission/2
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a local tag, you can use the command

```
git tag -d <tag_name>
```

To delete the remote tag, you have to use:

```
git push --delete origin <tag_name>
```

Note that when you do this, this will NOT delete the tag from other users' copies of the repository and if they push again, they will push the tag, so if you don't make the new tag quickly enough you may find the tag ressurects itself.

Comment: I tried deleteing, but i dont have access the remote tags. Is there any other option

Comment: I think you're probably out of luck, get in contact with the repository owner or a user with higher permissions and they'll need to help you out.